# Extract website details from text file using regex pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.7

Need to extract website urls from the text. Can you tell me where am I missing.

Data:

```
gmail.com

2.0

Dolphins.com.

B.TECH

62.1%.

github.com/XYZ

abcd.com

github.com/abcd

linkedin.com/in/abcd

abcd.wordpress.com/

https://xyz/stackoverflow.com
```

Regex pattern:

```
urls = re.findall('(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?[\w+/\-?=%.]+\.[\w+/\-?=%.]+', text)
```

Expected Output:

```
github.com/XYZ

abcd.com

github.com/abcd

linkedin.com/in/abcd

abcd.wordpress.com/

https://xyz/stackoverflow.com
```

Current output:

Its extracting all the items which are written in Data. Can someone tell me what changes are required in my regex to get the expected output?

Comment: What is the rule to decide if a string is a URL or not?

Answer (score 0):

I used below regex and it worked in regex101.com

```
.*(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-z-]+\.(?:com|org)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?.*
```

But when I use it in my code with re.findall() it returns entire text file, and if we use it with re.finditer() it says json is not serializable. Im trying to return my output in json. So what can be done here?